# Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined rails 5.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-5

this is what i have done

## in gem file

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

## in app js

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs   
//= require activestorage  
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

## my app html

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag   'application'  %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

# my error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined
```

Comment: having the same problem. are you perhaps using twitter bootstrap?